# Does Cabal have a default target?

Tags: haskell, cabal

If my .cabal file has multiple executables, I can single out one to build by typing the name

```
cabal build myExecutable
```

But I am lazy, and want to type just

```
cabal build
```

for a default target (I can stand the extra characters of typing for my secondary executables).

Is this possible?  (I've been google'ing and looking through the cabal manual for a while now....  No definitive answer yet).

I have to do this, like, 1000 times a day....

Comment: `cabal build` builds all targets unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hack something together with flags, e.g.:

```
    flag all
      default: False

   executable first-prog:
     buildable: True

   executable second-prog
     if flag(all)
       buildable: True
     else
       buildable: False

   executable third-prog:
     if flag(all)
       buildable: True
     else
       buildable: False
```

and then use `cabal configure -fall; cabal build` when you wanted to build everything.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the age old solution of writing a make file and just type

```
$ make
```

into your terminal.